# When is an empty route matched with prefix path match?

Tags: angular

Please take a look at routes

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/places/tabs/discover',
    pathMatch: 'full' 
  },
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    component: PlacesPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/places/tabs/offers',
        pathMatch: 'prefix'
      },
      {
        path: 'discover',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './discover/discover.module#DiscoverPageModule'
          },
          {
            path: ':placeId',
            loadChildren:
              './discover/place-detail/place-detail.module#PlaceDetailPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'offers',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './offers/offers.module#OffersPageModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'new',
            loadChildren:
              './offers/new-offer/new-offer.module#NewOfferPageModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'edit/:placeId',
            loadChildren:
              './offers/edit-offer/edit-offer.module#EditOfferPageModule'
          },
          {
            path: ':placeId',
            loadChildren:
              './offers/offer-bookings/offer-bookings.module#OfferBookingsPageModule'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

If I enter router `/places/tabs/discover` then I am redirected to `/places/tabs/offers`, because route

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/places/tabs/offers', pathMatch: 'prefix' }
```

matches `discover` part in route `/places/tabs/discover` (am I mistaken here?)

Should not route `''` match *none* route only?

Comment: I don't get why you consider empty route should be matched.

Comment: @jeprubio because `''` must match any loaded route given that pathMath equals `prefix`, unless it equals to `full`. That is why usually an empty path is accompanied by `pathMatch: 'full'`.

Comment: Path `''` does not match *any*. The path `''` will match *none*. If you want to match *any* then use a *wildcard*.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#define-a-wildcard-route

Comment: If you want to match `/offers/new` before a `/offers/**` wildcard, then place the wildcard lower in the route tree.

Comment: @Reactgular I have updated the question. Please take a look.
If I enter router `/places/tabs/discover` then I am redirected to `/places/tabs/offers`, because `{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/places/tabs/offers',
        pathMatch: 'prefix'
      }` matches `discover` part in `/places/tabs/discover` (am I mistaken here?). This is what I mean when saying that `''` matches any loaded route.